# Possible unintended reference comparison

Tags: c#

I have the following code which gives a warning

> Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'`

```
if (lblStatus.Content == "ACTIVE")
{
  //Do stuff
}
else
{
  //Do other Stuff
}
```

I'm assuming the warning is because `lblStatus.Content` may not necessarily always be of type string?

I've tried to fix it using each of the following but I still get a warning

```
if (lblStatus.Content.ToString() == "ACTIVE")
if ((string)lblStatus.Content == "ACTIVE")
if (lblStatus.Content === "ACTIVE")
```

Please could someone explain the reason I still get a warning and the best practical way to deal with this?

Comment: Your first two fixes will not give a warning, and the third won't compile.

Comment: The first two modifications should have fixed the problem. Did you try to recompile?

Comment: What is they type of lblStatus? I looks like a WPF or Silverlight TextBox. Is this correct?

Comment: What's the declared type of `Content`? I can't understand why you get a compiler warning when you call `.ToString()` or when you cast to `string`.

Comment: You probably didn't compile after changing the code. Warnings in the code view (shown as tooltips) might not be refreshed instantly.

Comment: If `Content` is declared of type `object` (base class of `string`) or some interface type (which `string` implements), then decide what you want to happen if `Content` is an object which is not a string?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The warning is because the *compile-time* type of `lblStatus.Content` is `object`. Therefore operator overloading chooses the `==(object, object)` overload which is just a reference identity comparison. This has nothing to do with what the *execution-time* type of the value is.

The first or second of your options *should* have fixed the warning though:

```
if (lblStatus.Content.ToString() == "ACTIVE")
if ((string)lblStatus.Content == "ACTIVE")
```

Note that the first of these will throw an exception if `lblStatus.Content` is null. I would prefer the second form.

If you think you're still seeing a warning at that point, I suspect you either haven't rebuilt - or something is still "dirty" in your build. A full rebuild *absolutely* should remove the warning.

Comment: "..._compile-time_ type of `lblStatus.Content` is a string" - not `object`?

Comment: @Rawling: Apparently today is the day of multiple typos :(

Comment: Thanks everyone - it just needed a rebuild to remove the warning. @Jon thanks for the helpful info on if `lblStatus.Content` is null.

Comment: Casting to `string` is best if you're sure the `Content` will never be an object that's not a string (which I guess is the case here). Otherwise, one could say `lblStatus.Content as string == "ACTIVE"` or check for `null` and do `ToString()` something else (depending on what one wants in that case).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to stick to the `string.Equals(string,string,StringComparison)` method, like this:

```cs
string contentStr = (lblStatus.Content ?? string.Empty).ToString();
if (string.Equals("ACTIVE", contentStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{ 
    // stuff
}
```

because it explicitly states what it does + it doesn't give a warning you've mentioned.

Comment: Your code doesn't achieve the same thing - it's case-insensitive for no obvious reason. Yes, you can *make* it case-sensitive, but then it's just a really long-winded way of achieving the same thing, *and* it will give a different result if `lblStatus.Content` is unexpectedly a non-string type whose `ToString` method happens to return "ACTIVE".

Comment: >> it will give a different result if lblStatus.Content is unexpectedly a non-string type whose ToString method happens to return "ACTIVE". - Good point, I didn't think about that.

Comment: The good thing about this is that no exception rises if `Content` is an object that's not a string (and whose `ToString()` implementation isn't completely evil), or if `Content` is `null`. But it's a little verbose.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Why is that a *good* thing? The OP expects that the value *is* a string reference (or null). If it's not, the OP's view of the world is broken, and an exception is entirely reasonable IMO. Better that than continuing to proceed pretending the world is a way that it's not.

Comment: agreed, this `(lblStatus.Content ?? string.Empty).ToString()` is a pitfall.

Comment: @JonSkeet Under your premise "The OP expects that the value _is_ a string reference (or null)", I totally agree! But like I said in a comment elsewhere, if it's OK that `Content` is neither `null` nor a string, if that doesn't break the OP's world, something has to be done. After all, the compile-time type of `Content` is not `string`, and maybe the reason for that is that `Content` might be something else. (But but I'm saying this more to generalize things; `lblStatus` sounds like a GUI label.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: If it's genuinely okay for that to be the case, I'd just use `if ((lblStatus.Content as string) == "ACTIVE")`

Comment: @JonSkeet, that's what I used to do(because generally I do not like verbose code). But after spending several sunday-evening-hours in catching a bug in our app(there was pretty similar case and we had replaced "ACTIVE" by "Active" on GUI, +sometimes I tend to be sort of inattentive :)) + I prefer to be verbose/explicit in writing string-comparison-related code.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan: I think we'll have to agree to differ. I think `==` is fairly clear - you don't need much experience to remember that it's ordinal case-sensitive comparison. If you don't *want* that kind of comparison, then yes, an explicit comparison is best. But I wouldn't *assume* that case-insensitive is definitely what's wanted.

Answer (score -5):

Rebuild your project after you fix your code with this :

```
if (lblStatus.Content.ToString() == "ACTIVE")
if ((string)lblStatus.Content == "ACTIVE")
if (lblStatus.Content === "ACTIVE")
```

Comment: There is no === operator in C#