# Perform a linq expression for 'contains' with searching through a list for 'like' not exact matches

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, poco

Okay so I am stumped and have looked around for this and I know I am doing the implementation of something very simple more complex than it needs to be.  Basically I have a POCO object that will have a member that contains a string of other members.  This is labeled as 'st' and it may have strings that are comma seperated series in one string.  Thus I may have two members of strings be 'images, reports' and another 'cms, crm'.  I have a list of objects that I want to match for PART OF those strings but not necessarily all as a DISTINCT LIST.  So a member of 'cms' would return the value of anything that contained 'cms' thus 'cms, crm' would be returned.

I want to hook this up so a generic List can be queried but I cannot get it to work and was looking at other threads but there methods do not work in my case.  I keep thinking it is something simple but I am missing it completely.  Please let me know if anyone has better ideas.  I was looking here but could not get the logic to apply correctly:

[Linq query list contains a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364090/linq-query-list-contains-a-list)

I keep trying methods of 'Select', 'SelectMany', 'Contains', 'Any', 'All' at different levels of scope of the continuations to no avail.  Here is a simple excerpt of where I am at with a simple Console app example:

```
public class Program
    {
        public class StringModel
        {
            public string name { get; set; }

            public string str { get; set; }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "";

            List<StringModel> sm = new List<StringModel>
                {
                    new StringModel
                        {
                            name = "Set1",
                            str = "images, reports"

                        },
                        new StringModel
                    {
                        name = "Set2",
                        str = "cms, crm"
                    },
                    new StringModel
                    {
                        name = "Set3",
                        str = "holiday, pto, cms"
                    }
                };

            sm.ForEach(x => s += x.name + "\t" + x.str + "\n");


            var selected = new List<object> {"cms", "crm"};

            s += "\n\nITEMS TO SELECT: \n\n";

            selected.ForEach(x => s += x + "\n");

            s += "\n\nSELECTED ITEMS: \n\n";

            // works on a single item just fine
        var result = sm.Where(p => p.str.Contains("cms")).Select(x => new { x.name, x.str}).ToList();

            // I am not using select to get POCO on other methods till I can get base logic to work.
            // Does not return anything
            var result2 =  sm.Where(p => selected.Any(x => x == p.str)).ToList();

            // Does not return anything
            var result3 = sm.Where(p => selected.Any(x => selected.Contains(p.str))).ToList();

            result.ForEach(y => s += y + "\n");

            s += "\n\n2nd SET SELECTED: \n\n";

            result2.ForEach(y => s += y + "\n");

            s += "\n\n3rd SET SELECTED: \n\n";

            result3.ForEach(y => s += y + "\n");


            Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result2` is empty because you're comparing an `object` (`x`) with a `string` (`StringModel.str`). This will be a [reference comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263715/possible-unintended-reference-comparison). Even if you convert `x` to a `string`, you'll be comparing each value in `selected` ("cms", "crm") with your comma-separated string values ("images, reports", "cms, crm", "holiday, pto, cms").

`result3` is empty because `selected` ("cms", "crm") does not contain any of the string values ("images, reports", "cms, crm", "holiday, pto, cms"), although in this case at least the comparisons are value comparisons.

I think you're looking for something like:

```
var result = sm.Where(p => selected.Any(x => p.str.Contains((string)x)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I would have NEVER thought to cast the type.  I had literally tried that method you gave MINUS the (string) before the x in the 'Contains()'  but it bombed so I assumed it would not work.  I should have thought to cast it as it was an object value but I appreciate a second set of eyes on it.