# SearchResultCollection class: object property value comparison

Tags: c#

I am having an issue here comparing the value of a SearchResultCollection object's property value with another value. A snippet of my code is seen below:

```
foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {
        result.Properties["<propertyname>"][0] == "FALSE"
    }
```

If I leave it at this, I'll get an error saying that "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side type to string. "

I know where I messed up, the left hand value is that of the SearchResultCollection type, whereas the the righthand side is a string. How should I go about fixing this so that they are comparable? The value that the property stores is either "TRUE" or "FALSE."

Comment: The left-hand side's type is not `SearchResultCollection`; it's `object` (`SearchResultCollection` is the type of `results`, I believe). If you know that the value is a string, then you simply need to cast it as string. Try `bool areEqual = (result.Properties["<propertyname>"][0] as string) == "FALSE";`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible unintended reference comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263715/possible-unintended-reference-comparison)

Comment: Because the left handside is an object, its trying to do a reference check because of the *operator overload resolution*, if that `string` is not *interned* (and there is a good chance its not), then it likely to fail regardless of its value

Comment: So in short, the compiler is asking you, "*do you feel lucky?*"