# Comparing a class that inherits an interface to an interface reference

Tags: c#

In my class `ClassA : ISomeInterface` i have:

```
public class ClassA : ISomeInterface {
    Entity entity;
    public void Test(){
       if(entity.Target == this){}
    }    
}
```

With `Target` in `entity` defined as:

```
public class Entity {     

   public ISomeInterface Target {get; private set;}    

}
```

My editor then gives me a warning:

```
Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison cast the LHS to type `Object`
```

[image]

Although it compiles, this is the first time I've had this warning. Should I not be comparing interface references like this?

Comment: I cant reproduce

Comment: @TheGeneral it comes from Resharper i think? But i am not sure why it is warning me as unintended...its making me think i should not be doing what i am doing for the comparison.

Comment: CS0252 is not R# warning - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0252... please re-read [MCVE] guidance on posting code as @TheGeneral hinted and [edit] the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Possible unintended reference comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12263778/1838048)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that was the minimal - its literally just a function with a comparison to a property reference of the interface.. thats it.

Comment: @Oliver i just read that but i don't fully understand the answer =/

Comment: Offensive comment, feel free to flag as such: there are 3 parts which are all required, it is not "minimal non-reproducible example" nor "minimal reproducible salmon"... Code shown in the post is not enough to get the same error...

Comment: What the heck did you find offensive in my comment??? Calm down. I have updated my answer with the code, it really wasn't hard to see the structure of the code before i made the edit, that is a literal copy paste and the error in the function with the if statement - R# gives the warning. If you don't have R# it doesn't show. I said this already and i still don't understand the meaning behind the warning even with the link to the possible duplicate.

Comment: No warning under VS2017 .NET 4.7.2... Perhaps to remove a code analysis addon warning you can write to compare references: `if ( entity.Target == (ISomeInterface )this ) {}` else take a look at the @Oliver answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already stated it is a warning not an error. And the warning tells you what the compiler really does and maybe your intentionnally guess what should happen is wrong.

So being said that, lets further dig what the problem could be. Here is some sample code (that what's being meant with please give an [complete example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/shD72G)):

```
using System;

public interface ISomeInterface
{
}

public class ClassA : ISomeInterface
{
    public ClassA(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public ISomeInterface Entity { get; set; }
    
    public static bool operator== (ClassA x, ClassA y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    public static bool operator!= (ClassA x, ClassA y)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 72;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        if (Entity == this)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("same");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("different");
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var first = new ClassA(1);
        var second = new ClassA(1);
        first.Entity = second;
        first.Test(); // writes "different"
    }
}
```

As you can see the code implements the equality comparers and `Equals()`. All these methods are saying that all instance are the same, but the call in `if(Entity == this)` still tells that they are different.

This is the meaning of the warning and the root cause is, that an equality check of an interface always falls back to the implementation within the type `object`. And that implementation is `ReferenceEquals(x, y)`.

So to avoid this warning and make your intention clear you should either explicitly write `if(ReferenceEquals(Entity, this))` or implement a stand-alone class that implements `IEqualityComparer<ISomeInterface>` and use an instance of it `if(new MyComparer().Equals(Enity, this))` (do not instantiate the comparer within the if statement in real code) to make your intentation of comparison obvious.